# Uploading file in web applications

Tags: http, browser, file-transfer

This may be immature question but...

- When we use html input file control to upload a file, OS encrypts! the full path of the file due to security. i.e.: `C:\falsepath\XXXXXX.txt`
- why security has to be enforced, since the client is the one  uploading the file, he obviously knows the location, why can't it just provide full path (client script)
- But how does server gets stream of bytes from client?

Can somebody explain me what is happening behind the screen?

OS-windows environment , Browsers -all

Comment: I don't know that this is the appropriate forum for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Server does not to know what is local path, browser sends to him stream of bytes. Local path is for good looking for user, nothing else.
If you ask: how does BROWSER know where the file is, this is good question, but you didn't write what is your OS.

Answer (score 0):

You should know, that the server is completely separated from the client.

The client application sends to the server a message, which contains the content of the file and a file name (just the name of the file, not the directory. The change of the actual name to the C:\falsepath* is made only to prevent scripts on client's side to know anything about the original location, which may contain sensitive information you don't want to publish.